# Successfully open but not good?

Tags: c++, file, stream

In C++, is there a case where `std::ifstream open()` can be successful, but `std::ifstream good()` can be false ?

EDIT : tested with g++ 4.7.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream filestream("testfile");
    std::cout<<filestream.good()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<filestream.eof()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<filestream.fail()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<filestream.bad()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will return : 1, 0, 0, 0 for an empty file which means `good = TRUE` and `eof = fail = bad = FALSE`. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After verifying the actual text in the standard, I don't think `eofbit` is allowed to be set after an `open`: `badbit` may be set if the actual open throws an exception (I think—the standard doesn't really say what should happen in this case); `failbit` should be set if the open fails, or if the seek after the open (if `ate` is set) fails; but there doesn't seem to be any case where `eofbit` may be set.

Not that calling `std::istream::good()` is a good solution in this case.  (It would be interesting to know what the OP is trying to achieve.  Whatever it is, calling `std::istream::good()` is probably not the right solution.)

If `std::ifstream::good()` returns `false`, the next input will fail.
If it returns `true`, it tells you nothing: the next input may succeed,
but it might also fail.

Comment: +1 the implementation might actually not test the file until you attempt a read and that read fails.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In general, it makes no sense to test the `eofbit` until an input has failed.  And the fact that `std::ifstream::good()` tests the `eofbit` (in addition to the other status bits) makes it pretty much worthless.

Comment: I don't think there's any *harm* in the questioner using `good` is there? It's just that since the `eofbit` isn't set, you might as well test the stream for truth like normal. I suppose there's readability harm in doing something pointlessly abnormal, and like you say pretty much any use of `good` is pointlessly abnormal...

Comment: @SteveJessop In this particular case, `good` is actually usable, because it is guaranteed that `eofbit` is false.  But the message it sends to the reader (that you don't know iostreams) remains.  Anytime you can use a "canonical" solution, you should, because doing something else sends a message that either you don't know the situation, or that there is something special about it which means that the canonical solution can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is empty the eofbit will be triggered but the file will still be open so yes.

Comment: My understanding was that eofbit is only set if an operation attempts to read past the end of the file.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm not sure.  It's certain that the implementation is not required to set `eofbit` if the file is empty, but I'm not sure that it isn't allowed to.  If `eofbit` is set, it means that the next input will fail because there is no data.  (If `eofbit` isn't set, it doesn't mean anything.)

Comment: This is incorrect per my readings of the standard. All status bits in the file stream are cleared when the underlying file buffer's `open()` succeeds. The status is set to `failbit` if the file buffer `open()` fails. Either way, the `eofbit` will be clear after the call to the file stream `open()`.

Comment: I've just tested it, and with g++ 4.7.1, if you open an empty file : `good = TRUE`, `eof = fail = bad = FALSE`. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 1):

`ifstream::open` returns void, so be careful exactly what you mean by saying it's "successful".

The standard says for `basic_ifstream::open` (27.9.1.9):

> Effects: Calls rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::in). If that function
>   does not return a null pointer calls clear(), otherwise calls
>   setstate(failbit) (which may throw ios_base::failure)

So, if the call to open on the filebuf returns a value indicating success, then `ifstream::open` clears all the error bits, and so `good()` necessarily returns true.

If the call to open on the filebuf returns a value indicating failure, then `ifstream::open` can nevertheless return without throwing an exception. This behavior could be confused with "success", but in this case `good()` returns false because the failbit is set.

It's not entirely clear to me why this sets the failbit rather than the badbit, but I don't think my lack of understanding gets in the way of reporting the facts :-)